# MouseListener: Determine if mousePressed .getSource() == MouseReleased .getSource()

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

How can I check if the user releases the mouse on the same button they press the mouse?

I want to handle the case where the user clicks `button1`, continues to hold down the mouse button, then drags to `button2` and RELEASES the mouse on `button2`, where `button1` and `button2` are JButtons that I have added MouseListeners to.

> That is: **if the user clicks `button1`, and releases the mouse on
>   `button1`, do `action1()`.**
>
> And: **if the user clicks `button1`, and releases the mouse on
>   `button2`, do nothing.**

I have tried checking if `ePressed.getSource() == eReleased.getSource()`, but source seems to remain the same after dragging the mouse.

See below:

```
// My thoughts are that if the button is released on the source it was
// pressed, it should print "test", however "test" prints even if I 
// drag the mouse outside of the bounds of the button and release it
public JButton getSqaure() {
  JButton jb = new JButton();

  jb.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    boolean pressed = false;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
        pressed = true;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
      if (e.getSource() == jb && pressed) {
        System.out.println("test");
      }

      pressed = false;
    }
  });

  jb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));

  return jb;
}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question; but any reason to not just use `addActionListener` which responds only to clicks as you'd expect them to behave on a `JButton`?  I.e. do you _need_ to track times when the mouse is pressed on the button, but it then chooses to release the mouse over some other component?

Comment: That was my original idea - however I want to do different actions on right/left mouse clicks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course - I have answered my own question:

```
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
  pressed = false;
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
  pressed = true;
}
```

Comment: Note that my original code `e.getSource() == jb` in the if statement was also unnecessary